# Two mappings with constant composition

Tags: functions

Can you tell me if my answer is correct? Thank you so much!!!

Here is the problem:
If $f,g$ are mappings of $S$ into $S$ and $f\circ g$ is a *constant* function, then

(a) What can you say about $f$ if $g$ is onto?

(b) What can you say about $g$ if $f$ is 1-1.

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRtTo.jpg)

As $f\circ g$ is a constant function, $f\circ g$ is neither onto nor 1-1.

If $g$ is onto, $f$ cannot be onto because if $f$ is onto and $g$ is onto, $f\circ g$ would be onto.

If $f$ is $1-1$, $g$ cannot be 1-1 because if $f$ is 1-1 and $g$ is 1-1, $f\circ g$ would be 1-1.

In any case, the range of $g$ must be a subset of the domain of $f$.

Comment: "If g is onto, f cannot be onto because if f is onto and g is onto, fg would be onto."  True.  But you can make a *much* stronger observation.  The image of S is not S as f is not onto.  So what *can* you say about the image of S.

Comment: How do you know that $S$ has more than one element? If it's a 1-element set, then $f$ is both 1-1 and onto.

Comment: $f \circ g$ is onto if $S$ is a single point.

Comment: If S has a single point or is the empty set then any function if one to one, onto and constant.  If we assume S has more than one element then your first observation would be true but not complete.  Your second has what I assume was a typo.

Comment: "the range of g must be a subset of the domain of f" as f and g are functions the domain of f and g are all of S, so this is always true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g$ is onto then you can write (for $y$ with $g(y)=x$):

$$f(x)=f(g(y))=\text{constant}$$

If $f$ is 1:1 then it has a [left inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Left_and_right_inverses) $f^{-1}$. Thus:

$$g(x)=f^{-1}(f(g(x)))=f^{-1}(\text{constant})=\text{constant}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I made a graph and I understood your answers. I like how you wrote the second part. It is very clear. I guess that you used that 1-1 functions have inverses, however to have inverses well-defined bijections are needed, right? Here we have just 1-1? How you justify inverses if we do not have bijections? However, for the first part, I do not understand how you can justify that f(x)=f(g(y))=constant. Can you expand/explain more that part? But now I understand why for part a) f(x) is a constant and for part b) g(x) is a constant, as well!!!

Comment: The restriction on $f$ on the co-domain to $f:S\rightarrow \text{Range}(f)$ is a well-defined bijection, and this is what I used. If you don't want to use this, you may do like others said: $f$ constant implies $f(g(x))=f(g(y))$ which by 1:1 property implies $g(x)=g(y)$ for all $x$ and $y$, so $g$ is constant.

Comment: Very nice!!! What about the first part? How can you justify that f(x)=f(g(y))=constant. Can you expand/explain me more that part? I understand why for part a) f(x) is a constant because I made a graph, but I would like to know how to write it.

Comment: Consider $x\in S$. $g$ is onto, therefore there exist $y\in S$ such that $g(y)=x$. Then $f(x)=f(g(y))=f\circ g(y)=\text{constant}$, since $f\circ g$ is constant.

Comment: Fair enough! Thank you so much!

Comment: Errata: In my comment above, one should read "$f\circ g$ constant implies $f(g(x))=f(g(y))$"...

Comment: Injective functions are not invertible. Thus do not have left inverse. Check it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function I believe that you need to use contradiction, what do you think?

Comment: Check the sections "Injections can be undone" and "Injections may be made invertible" in your link.

Comment: Thank you for all you help!

Answer (score 2):

An informal, yet correct, answer provided you know what all the terms *mean* can be:

$g$ is onto means $g(S) = \{g(x)|x \in S\}$ can, and *will* be anything.  So $f(g(x))$ can, and will, have $g(x)$ being any value yet $f(g(x))$ is constant so if $g(x)=y$ is .... anything....$f(y)$ is constant.  So $f$ is constant.

$f$ is 1-1 means different input of $f$ will have different output.  So if $f(g(x)) = f(g(y)) = c$ is constant then the output of $f$ is the *same* for all possible input of $g(x)$ or $g(y)$and the only way *that* can happen is if the input is the same.  So all the $g(x)$ or $g(y)$ are the same no matter what $x$ or $y$ are.  So $g$ is constant.

It's informal, but those *are* the arguments and reasoning.

Comment: I like your answer! Very interesting! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hints/Solutions:

(a) $f$ is constant.

(b) $g$ is constant.

Comment: A bit heavy on the solutions and light on the hints...

Comment: @fleablood Indeed, this is of course the best way!

Comment: Oh, I don't know....  I think hints without solutions are ideal.  In this case it's sort of hard to give a proper hint without giving it all away.

Comment: @fleablood I certainly respect your opinion, no argument there. :)

Comment: I really appreciate your help! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

1) If $g$ is onto then for any $x \in S$ there is a $y \in S$ so that $g(y) = x$.

So for every $x \in S$ there is some $y \in S$ so that $f(x) = f(g(y))$.  So what does that tell us about $f$?

2) If $f$ is 1-1 then for any $x \ne y$ we know $f(x) \ne f(y)$ so what can we say about $f(g(x))$ and $f(g(y))$ are those ever equal?  Never equal? What does that tell us about $g(x)$ and $g(y)$?

Comment: Thank you so much for those brilliant ideas!

Comment: Excellent questions! I made a graph to solve them...